# Cannot see Website tab in Azure portal

Tags: azure

My Azure portal looks different from those in the Microsoft videos.  Mine (in Silverlight) has:

- Home
- Hosted Services, Storage Accounts & CDN
- Database
- Data Sync
- Reporting
- Service Bus, Access Control & Caching
- Virtual Network

I can't see the Web Site section to deploy simple websites.  How do I enable it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the old portal. You need to get access to the preivew portal to see the websites section.
At the bottom of the page (The portal page, it will be in a bar across the bottom) should be a link to "Go to Preview Portal" click on that and follow the instructions.

Comment: if you're still not seeing Web Sites in the left sidebar, then as @Pharao2k mentioned, you're not signed up for that preview feature.  You can do so by going to your Account page (https://account.windowsazure.com) and selecting the "Preview Features" sub menu.

Answer (score 2):

Did you enter the Website preview program?